# For each control loop only affecting one Control

Tags: c#, loops, foreach, controls

I will try to keep this as specific as possible.

This is my code:

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
    if (c.Height > 25)
    {
        c.BackColor = Color.Red;
        pictureBox1.Location = new Point(x1, y1);
        if (pictureBox1.Bounds.IntersectsWith(c.Bounds))
        {
            isCollide = true;
            label1.Text = "true";
            c.BackColor = Color.Green;
        }
        else
        {
            isCollide = false;
            label1.Text = "false";
        }

    }
}
```

My goal is to loop through all of the controls on my form, and detect all of which have more than 25 pixels in height, which determines whether or not they are a wall in my game.

The "isCollide" variable which is being set to "true" simply makes it so that I cannot run through it.

The problem is that it only affects 1 picture box (wall). However, I have chosen to change the colour of all the selected controls to green as a check to see which controls are affected by the loop, and yet this affects all walls as it should..

**My question is**, why does the color affect all the controls that my code looped through, but the collision detection doesn't work on them all? Is it because the "isCollide" variable is set to "false" and "true" at the same time due to colliding with one wall and simultaneously NOT colliding with another?

**How may I remedy this problem?**

This is the code which uses "isCollide":

```
  public void move(string Direction)
    {
        if (Direction == "Up")
        {
            //b = x / a = y
            reset();
            x1 = x;
            y1 = y - 5;
            isCollided();
            if (isCollide == false)
            {
                y -= 5;
            }


        }
```

*Note: Not the end of the code, similar code has been applied to all directions (top, left, right, bottom)

Comment: Show me the code that uses isCollide and does logic based on it. This code is where you set isCollide. I want to see how you are using isCollide

Comment: Edit* : Looks messy. I'll update on the original post.

Comment: that code is syntactically incorrect to start of with. isCollide is field not a method so you can't invoke it with the '()' like you have it isCollided()

Comment: I think you misread it, sir. :) They're two different things. isCollideD is a method which determines the bool value (true/false) of isCollide.

Comment: well it will always be set to whatever the last control is then. And you are using global variables in a very bad way. Another hint is to name your methods something like getIsCollide so you don't have to member named the exact same thing. Basically there is just a lot wrong here.

Comment: Care to explain how? - I'd appreciate if you kept your advice relevant to the problem I asked, thanks. I do appreciate your help but I don't think it's necessary in that context.

Comment: I can't do your homework for your man. You will never learn. Start simple and define your own classes.

Comment: I do not understand why you assume it's my homework. Nonetheless thanks for your time.

Comment: Here is a good link to check out: http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C-Sharp-Fundamentals-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners

Comment: I'll wait for someone else to answer, thanks for your support. ;)

Comment: Second thought - didn't think you deserved to get away with your arrogance.

So I thought I'd inform you that you're wrong again, I have not used any Global variable in my code, it's a local one which I defined, you were just fooled by the auto-color that SO applied to code. Be a little more humble to users when they sincerely need advice please.

Comment: Lol I'm not fooled my friend. I was not referring to a "Global" variable in the literal term. But good luck I hope you figure out your problem but with the info provided no one on here will be able to help you much more.

Comment: Just curious though...how does the compiler not blow up if isCollide is not a global variable and you don't declare it nor do you pass it in to your method of "Move". It is then either a global variable in the since that it is not defined in that scope or your program will not compile.

Comment: Move takes in a sring.

isCollide is a local one I declared within the same class for the purpose of

Comment: Did you not include it? because according to the code you pasted you try to access isCollide and it hasn't even been defined yet.

Comment: Where do you define isCollide?? That is what I'm asking

Comment: Main form class, top of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final value of isCollide will be based on the collision of the last control that is iterated through in the foreach loop. If you don't care which object the collision occurs with, I recommend breaking out of the loop once a collision is found.
Something like this.

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
    if (c.Height > 25)
    {
        c.BackColor = Color.Red;
        pictureBox1.Location = new Point(x1, y1);
        if (pictureBox1.Bounds.IntersectsWith(c.Bounds))
        {
            isCollide = true;
            label1.Text = "true";
            c.BackColor = Color.Green;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            isCollide = false;
            label1.Text = "false";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think he wants the collision set for each control. At least thats what the question makes it sound like.

Answer (score 0):

Its because `isCollide` is just a **local variable** and not a **property** of your control like your `c.BackColor` is.

You need to define `isCollide` on your Control class to retain the state of isCollide for each control object in your Controls list:

```
public class Control
{
   public bool isCollide {get; set;}
   public string BackColor {get; set;}
   public int Height {get; set;}
}

foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
        {
            if (c.Height > 25)
            {
                c.BackColor = Color.Red;
                pictureBox1.Location = new Point(x1, y1);
                if (pictureBox1.Bounds.IntersectsWith(c.Bounds))
                {
                    c.isCollide = true;
                    label1.Text = "true";
                    c.BackColor = Color.Green;
                }
                else
                {
                    c.isCollide = false;
                    label1.Text = "false";
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! :D

I have the loop within my main code (being the main form class)
I cannot create a property for a Control, so how would I go about applying this method into my problem? :)

Comment: Why can you not add a property to the control?

Comment: What do you want to happen when isCollide is set then? It needs to set some other control property then I assume

Comment: Perhaps I can, will you please show me how I would do this? (Add an "isCollide" bool property to my controls - so that I can access it.

Comment: right click on one of your control objects and then select "go to definition". This will take you to the control class where you should be able to add a property like I wrote, unless the control class is in an external dll or something

Comment: I don't see the "Go to definition" option on my picturebox after I right click on it. :( Is there another way to access the class?

Answer (score 0):

A different reason could be that the controls on your form are nested into containers (e.g. `GroupBox`).
In this case you would have to recursively check the elements in *their* `Control` property as well.